# Не выводит цветной текст через colorama под Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Использую colorama для вывода цветного текста в консоль. Когда я запускаю скрипт у меня выводятся непонятные символы и рядом с ними мой текст без цвета. Использую Python 3.5. ОС Windows 10 PRO, простая консоль Windows

Comment: Для начала, нужно определиться с какой операционной системой работаете и какой консолью (терминалом) пользуетесь

Comment: Изменил, Windows 10 PRO простой терминал, может это из-за того что Windows 10 не активирована?

Comment: Вероятно, скрипт пытается использовать ANSI color codes, которые виндовой консолью не поддерживаются.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов именно поэтому используют colorama модуль, который транслирует ANSI коды для цветов в соответствующие win32 вызовы. Автор вероятно забыл colorama.init() вызвать. Нужен минимальный пример кода и вывода посмотреть.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо вам большое, я действительно забыл добавить init() и у меня теперь всё заработало)) Спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Цвет текста и фона в терминале Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899058/%d0%a6%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-python)

Answer (score 7):

Вот и всё:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back
init()

print(Fore.RED + 'Hello')
```