# Цвет текста и фона в терминале Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Я пробовал *Colorama* не работает, также пробовал *Termcolor* тоже не работает. 
Попрошу ссылку на материал (сам не нашёл) или же пример с объяснением.

P.s. Python 3.7
код:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Вот что выдало:!!!

```
[31msome red text
[42mand with a green background
[2mand in dim text
[0m
back to normal now
```

ОС: Windows 7
Терминал/Консоль: CMD
Запускаю 2-мя кликами по файлу через Python.exe

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85009/discussion-on-question-by-netexplorer-------python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы работаете в *Windows*, нужно в начале *инициализировать*, чтобы *отфильтровать управляющие ANSI последовательности с вывода на консоль*, и вместо того использовать их для смены цвета.

Добавите `init` к импорту и примените эту функцию в начале, т. е. вместо

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
```

используйте

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()
```

Потому что вы это не сделали, генерированные ANSI последовательности для смены цвета (начинающие симболом Esc, который на терминале изображен как `[`) *не испольняются, а просто выведутся на консоль*.